# Why does my code run successfully but give not output?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I am trying to open a text file with name 'P' and show the lines as an output. I wrote the code below, and it runs but not output. Why is this so?

```
with open('/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/P.txt','rt') as a_file:
    for lines in a_file.readlines():
        print(lines,ends='')`
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: Are you sure about the the path `/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/P.txt`, you should either use an absolute path or you can use a relative one but it has to be reachable from the directory you run the script from.

Comment: 1. Have you checked the exit code of your program. On Linux/Mac it would be `echo $?`. For normal termination it should be 0, other value means an error during the execution. 2. Does this file actually contain any text lines?

Comment: Also, `ends` is an invalid argument for `print`, did you mean `end=''`?

Comment: Your `print()` has `ends` instead of `end`. You should be getting a TypeError exception, so it seems you're reading an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

because your print contains `end=""`

usually the `\n` is used to flush the output.

if you want to force it to flush the buffer (so to print it without the `\n`) you can add the `flush` option :

```py
print(lines,end='', flush=True)
```

But maybe you just want to remove the end keyword:

```
print(lines)
```

**When to use `end=''`?**
When you use the end parameter you replace the usual `\n` (carret return) by something else, that is useful if you want to display a série of things next to each other without going next line everytime. (for instance if you want to print a dot `.` or `x` for each call to a function that you're calling in a loop for a big number of times.

And yes it should be `end` and not `ends`

See reference here :
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp

Comment: @mawunya it doesn't solve the problem? tell me, so I can edit my answer if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where you got `ends=''` from, but if you remove it, it produces an output.

I also figured I would also add that you are most likely referring to `end`, this will essentially just replace the `\n` which is the default value with whatever you wish.